# Network access failure in spawned process

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, process, spawn

I'm trying to spawn `cordova prepare` (fetching and installing cordova project dependencies) like this:

```js
Promise.all([
  fs.ensureDir('cordova/plugins'),
  fs.ensureDir('cordova/www'),
])
  .then(() => runCmd('cordova prepare', {cwd: './cordova'}));


function runCmd(cmd: string, options?: SpawnOptions): Promise<void> {
  const [theCmd, ...args] = cmd.split(' ');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const childProcess = spawn(theCmd, args, options);
    childProcess.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));
    childProcess.stderr.on('data', data => console.error(data.toString()));
    childProcess.on('close', code => code === 0 ? resolve() : reject(cmd + ' errored with code ' + code));
  });
}
```

But it fails with:

> Discovered platform "ios@^5.0.1" in config.xml or package.json. Adding it to
>   the project
>
> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^5.0.1
>
> Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@^5.0.1 Probably this is
>   either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Check your
>   connection and platform name/version/URL. Error: npm: Command failed
>   with exit code 1 Error output: npm ERR! Darwin 19.0.0 npm ERR! argv
>   "/Users/Birowsky/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node"
>   "/Users/Birowsky/Projects/Personal/GotaGuy/gotaguy-frontend/node_modules/.bin/npm"
>   "install" "cordova-ios@^5.0.1" "--production" "--no-save" npm ERR!
>   node v10.16.3 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
>
> npm ERR! Invalid version: "0" npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you need help, you
>   may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   /Users/Birowsky/Projects/Personal/GotaGuy/gotaguy-frontend/cordova/npm-debug.log

Am I maybe spawning it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I had `cordova` in my `package.json` which depends on `cordova-lib` which depends on a very old version of `npm`.

I installed a recent version of `npm` and the issue was gone : /